# How to figure out why Glue Schema Registry Avro Schema Evolution failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, avro

I'm using the AWS Glue Schema Registry to manage my AVRO schemas. Now, in case of an error during schema evolution, the SchemaVersion is marked as "Failed". However, how can I find out why the evolution failed?
Of course, one can compare the old and new schema, but isn't there a way to see a more specific error message?

- I searched in the AWS console
- I retrieved the schema versions via CLI, but you only see the "failed" status there as well
- I used `software.amazon.awssdk.services.glue.GlueClient` to fetch the schema, with the same result

There must be a way to more precisely pinpoint the error.

Thank you for your help.